# What is the meaning of: Xorg, display manager, X server ?

Tags: xorg, terminology

I don't really have a problem, I was just wondering where I could find some documentation about what exactly X server, Xorg, LightDM and stuff like that does.. I always stumble upon those terms, I know they have something to do regarding the graphics, but I'd like to know more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

X-Windows is a Unix/Linux Client-Server system. Although usually on the same computer, the Client and Server can be on different computers, unlike Microsoft Windows.

X11 is a network protocol. It encodes things such as graphic primitives, images, pointer motion, and key presses.

X clients are graphical applications like Firefox.

Xorg is an X server. It implements X11 and provides an interface to keyboards, mice, and video cards.

Gnome, KDE, LXDE, and Xfce are desktop environments. They provide libraries and specifications that applications use

When running X-Windows, instead of a console login, the Display Manager i.e. Lightdm starts up. The DM starts the X-server and asks for login credentials and then launches the user's desktop environment.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

For background information on applications running on Ubuntu I always find the following resources useful:

- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/)
- [Ubuntu User Documentation / Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/)

For deeper insights or other views on applications that run in different distributions we can also find a lot here:

- [Ubuntu Package Information](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) often give a link to a project's home page
- [GNOME Wiki](https://live.gnome.org/) for anything related to GNOME
- [freedesktop.org Wiki](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Home)
- [Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org)
- [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/)
- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) with its basic informations and its links to relevant pages
- [Google](https://www.google.com/)! No kidding, this is way fastest to find a project's page

This list is incomplete, I know.

Answer (score 0):

This architectural overview is a bit outdated, but still mostly applies:

http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-Overview-HOWTO/index.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.